# Yii2 Pjax Pagination On multiple Gridview not working

Tags: php, yii2

Have One Page 2 Gridview Table . Pagination Does not work properly ,

Here is the Code :

```
// table 1
 <?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'table_1']); ?>
                 <?= GridView::widget([
                  // 
                  ]); ?>
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
// Table 2
 <?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'table_2']); ?>
                 <?= GridView::widget([
                  // 
                  ]); ?>
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is already explained in [the guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-widgets#multiple-gridviews-on-one-page) and here I quote.

> You can use more than one GridView on a single page but some additional configuration is needed so that they do not interfere with each other. When using multiple instances of GridView you have to configure different parameter names for the generated sort and pagination links so that each GridView has its own individual sorting and pagination. You do so by setting the sortParam and pageParam of the dataProvider's sort and pagination instances.

In your case:

```
use yii\grid\GridView;

$tbl1Provider->pagination->pageParam = 'tbl1_page'; 
$tbl2Provider->pagination->pageParam = 'tbl2_page'; 

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $tbl1Provider,
]);

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $tbl2Provider,
]);
```

Comment: Its simple GridView , I m asking pagination og Gridview using Pjax

Comment: did you just test what I wrote? Its dealing with Pagination

Comment: Yes ,  Buts its not about PJAX . its about Multiple Pagination .